# Does Major Garbage Collection collect object from both generations?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As we know when object is created it is stored in eden space inside new generation, then moved to survivor spaces (if alive) and subsequently to old generation.

My question is - does major garbage collection clean objects of old generation only or cleans new and old generation both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three types of collection in the HotSpot for Parallel and Concurrent Mark Sweep.  There is the minor collection which is just the Eden or the Eden and survivor spaces. A full collection which is everything, and a concurrent collection which is only the old generation.  There is no major collection as such.  The term full collection is more often used and clearer as to its meaning.

The G1 collector has two generations young and old, but only one collection type and has relatively continuous collections. It might clean just 1 MB or potentially all the memory.

The Azul JVM is purely concurrent in all generations.

Comment: G1 has two generation and distinguish between young and old collections.

Answer (score 1):

For HotSpot JVM:

- Mark Sweep Compact collectors (Serial, Parallel scavenge, Parallel old) are collecting both young and old during old collection.
  If case of insufficient size of old space, these collector could switch to non-generational mode (effectively doing only full collections).
- Concurrent Mark Sweep old collection collects only old space. But if concurrent collection fails it falls back to Stop-The-World Mark Sweep Compact Full collection and collects both spaces.
- G1 has young collection and old collection. Young collection collects only young space. Old collection normally collects a portion of old space (G1 is incremental). In case is incremental mode fails it fall back to Full GC collecting all spaces.

Take a look at [GC switches cheatsheet](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/09/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) for JVM configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

> When the young generation fills up, a young generation collection (sometimes referred to as a minor collection) of just that generation is performed. When the old or permanent generation fills up, what is known as a full collection (sometimes referred to as a major collection) is typically done. That is, all generations are collected.

- [Memory Management in the Java HotSpotTM Virtual Machine Sun Microsystems April 2006](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)